# Is the Journal of Data Science still alive?

Tags: journals, data-science

Does anyone one know whether the Journal of Data Science is still working or not? I have noticed that the journal's website (http://jds-online.com/) has not been updated since last year.

Comment: According to the website there is a new editor - a Michael Lee. It might be a good idea to contact him via email, which is listed right on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely that a definitive answer would be available unless the site happens to host a member of the journal's editorial board.

However, their publication follows a January - April - July - October pattern. It's now May, and their last published edition was in January, which means they have missed at least one issue. However, the January 2014 issue also announces a new editor, so they may simply have a disrupted schedule without being "dead".

So I'd say "Not healthy, but possibly still alive". Another missed issue in July would be a pretty negative sign. Alternately, you could try contacting the journal to find out?

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. I will wait a bit then.